# Как удалить заданный пользователем элемент списка?

Tags: c, указатели, структуры

Задана структура для списка. Как удалить заданный пользователем элемент этого списка? Код работает неправильно - удаляет все элементы списка

```
delete_3(Person *lst){
    int num = 0;
    printf("Какой элемент удалять?\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    Person *p;
    p = lst;
    do {
        p->name[0] = '\0';
        p->job[0] = '\0';
        p->home[0] = '\0';
        print_2(lst);
        p = p->ptr;
    } while (p != NULL);
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Сможете помочь?

Comment: Для того чтобы вам помочь, вы должны отредактировать свой вопрос согласно моему сообщению выше.

Comment: Готово! .......

Comment: А зачем Вы вводите `num`, если далее эта переменная никак не используется?

Comment: это номер строки, которую должен ввести пользователь. ее и надо удалить из списка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы затираете каждую строку, каждого элемента в цикле, а вам всего лишь нужно перекинуть указатель на следующий элемент.

```
delete_3(Person *lst){
    int num, i = 0;
    printf("Какой элемент удалять?\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    Person *p;
    p = lst;
    while (p != NULL && i < num){
        p = p->ptr;
        ++i
    }

    if(p != NULL){
        if(num == 0){
          lst = p->ptr;
        } else if(p->ptr != NULL){
          p->ptr = p->ptr->ptr;
        } else {
          p->ptr = NULL;
        }
    }

    print_2(lst);
}
```

Comment: Допустим, список:
Михаил
Мария
Алия
Иван
Выполнив код несколько раз, у меня будут удаляться элементы снизу, а не указанная строка

Comment: Не получается удалить именно указанную строку в списке

Comment: в смысле если выполнить код несколько раз, то удалятся элементы снизу? Ну да, если вы удалите 2 строку 2 раза, то удалится 2 элемента, а не один.

Comment: поправил кстати удаление первого элемента

Comment: спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Можно же сразу откинуть вариант с 0 строкой, зачем цикл запускать? Что-то типа: `if (!lst) return; if (num == 0) print_2(lst->ptr);` и так далее — проще и понятнее.